# Navigating an XML doc with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a simple XML doc that looks like the following:

```
<Lineup>
 <Player>
    <GameID>20150010</GameID>
    <GameDate>2015-04-06T00:00:00-04:00</GameDate>
    <DH>0</DH>
    <TeamId>16</TeamId>
    <PlayerId>458913</PlayerId>
    <LineupPosition>1</LineupPosition>
    <DefensivePosition>8</DefensivePosition>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <GameID>20150010</GameID>
    <GameDate>2015-04-06T00:00:00-04:00</GameDate>
    <DH>0</DH>
    <TeamId>16</TeamId>
    <PlayerId>607054</PlayerId>
    <LineupPosition>2</LineupPosition>
    <DefensivePosition>4</DefensivePosition>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <GameID>20150010</GameID>
    <GameDate>2015-04-06T00:00:00-04:00</GameDate>
    <DH>0</DH>
    <TeamId>16</TeamId>
    <PlayerId>455976</PlayerId>
    <LineupPosition>3</LineupPosition>
    <DefensivePosition>9</DefensivePosition>
  </Player>
</Lineup>
```

I'm attempting to loop through each player object and individually access every single child node and its respective value. I'm trying something like the following:

```
xml_doc.xpath("//Lineup/Player").each do |lineup|
  puts "lineup: #{lineup.inspect}"
end
```

I'm not entirely sure how to access individual children elements of `lineup` here though. What's the best way to do this using nokogiri?

Comment: You mean [`Nokogiri::XML::Node.children`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the XPath `/Lineup/Player/*` to inspect each child element of each "Player" node:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('my.xml'))
doc.xpath('/Lineup/Player/*').each do |node|
  puts "#{node.name}: #{node.text}"
end
# GameID: 20150010
# GameDate: 2015-04-06T00:00:00-04:00
# DH: 0
# ...etc...
```

Alternatively, you can select each "Player" and iterate over its [element children (by using `#elements` or `#element_children`)](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#element_children-instance_method):

```
doc.xpath('/Lineup/Player').each do |player|
  puts "-- NEXT PLAYER --"
  player.elements.each do |node|
    puts "#{node.name}: #{node.text}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was hoping to be able to do something like: `foo = player.foo` in the iteration, so I wouldn't need to check what `node.name` is in every iteration. Is that also possible?

Comment: @randombits: not directly but you could create a "Player" factory or constructor function which takes a Player element and populates the member variables necessary for those accessor functions (or by using [`#method_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)).